# Not Exists not showing results as it suppose to SQL Server 2015 query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know this question might be answered too many times but I am not able to find the reason why this is happening.

I have 2 tables and I am trying to select rows who are not exists in table 2 from table 1 but when I ran that query it didn't show any results even though I am 100% sure there are rows in table 1 that are not in table 2. My query is similar to like the following:

```
select pid from tbl1 where not exists ( select pid from tbl2)
```

I know there are other ways to achieve that I just want to understand the concept of why it is not working.

Thank you very much.

Comment: There is no SQL Server **2015** - we have 2012, 2014, 2016, 2017 and 2019 - take your pick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NOT EXISTS` checks if **there are no rows** in the subquery. Your subquery should be correlated, but since it isn't it doesn't behave as you expect.

As is it, if your subquery selects any rows, then the condition is not met, and the predicate fails for all rows. That means, your query won't return any rows at all.

The only case when your query will return rows is when the table `tbl2` is empty.

**Solution #1: Use IN**

Now, you can use the correlated subquery as other answers show here, or you can use `IN` instead, if `tbl2` never has nulls. For example:

```
select pid from tbl1 where pid not in (select pid from tbl2)
```

**Solution #2: Use EXCEPT**

```
select pid from tbl1
except
select pid from tbl2
```

**Solution #3: Use an anti-join**

```
select a.pid
from tbl1 a
left join tbl2 b on b.pid = a.pid
where b.pid is null
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a correlation clause:

```
select pid
from tbl1
where not exists (select 1 from tbl2 where tbl2.pid = tbl1.pid)
-------------------------------------------^ correlation clause
```

The column returned by the subquery does not matter -- only whether or not it returns rows.  The correlation clause does what you want.  In your case, if `tbl2` has any rows, then the subquery returns a row and `NOT IN` returns false.

You may be confusing `NOT EXISTS` with `NOT IN`.  That said, I strongly recommend using `NOT EXISTS` instead of `NOT IN`.

Comment: NOT EXISTS behaves as expected in the presence of nulls unlike NOT IN. Also NOT EXISTS is usually more performant than NOT IN.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `IN` clause,

```
select pid from tbl1 where pid  not in ( select pid from tbl2)
```

If you want to use `exists` you need to define the join conditions

```
select pid from tbl1 where not exists ( select pid from tbl2 where tbl2.pid = tbl1.pid)
```